# Install Nvidia dual-graphics driver on Loki?

Tags: greeter, release-loki, suspend, nvidia

Currently running Freya on a 2+ years old machine that came with Nvidia dual graphics (GeForce GT 740M). On Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 17 and Elementary 0.3.2, I have had to install Nvidia proprietary drivers using the 'Additional Drivers' dialog box, but I tried the Loki Beta 2 and didn't find this in the menu.

Without this, my laptop simply does not wake up from suspend or even lock screen. As soon as the screen sleeps, I have to force shutdown my laptop and restart it.

However, the solution I found to be working was to install Nvidia binary driver version 352.63. It also install an app 'nvidia-settings' wherein I have to ask it to use Intel graphics on power-saving mode, to get the screen to behave as expected.

Will there be an option to install and use proprietary drivers as easy as it is in Freya? Would I have to find another way to install it in Loki? If so, what would that be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have dual graphics, but I do have a Haswell based machine with a GTX 960. I installed the release version of Loki and had slow, stuttering Nouveau graphics even though I had selected to install proprietary drivers during installation. This is what I did to fix it, afterwards I had fully accelerated binary drivers from Nvidia and a smooth, fast desktop experience.

Open a terminal and type `sudo ubuntu-drivers list`. You should see the Nvidia driver version that matches your card listed. If so, type `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and the system will install the correct driver and any needed dependencies. Reboot, and you should have the correct driver installed. Note that your boot splash screen will be replaced with boot messages in a low resolution, however once the display manager loads you'll have fully accelerated graphics.

Comment: I moved to Loki in expectation that bugs with proprietary drivers would be solved. Now I have n+1 bugs. Happy...

Comment: It showed me several compatible versions. I was already using an older version via Nvidia's PPA, but the newer one worked just as fine, and I can now remove the PPA.

Answer (score -2):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo apt install nvidia-XXX nvidia-settings

Important!!!!

Go to nvidia.com and looking for the right driver. For GeForce GT 740M it is 367.44 today. So:

sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-settings