# Installing bumblebee in Loki

Tags: release-loki, nvidia, bumblebee

I tried installing bumblebee on Elementary OS Loki, but without luck. Can anybody help me with this? I would like the better battery life and the better graphics when needed.
I have a GTX 970M.

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7548/6831) answer solved my problem. I did a `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee` and followed the steps. You do the switch from NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles