# Loki freezes and black screen after suspend

Tags: release-loki, suspend

I've installed loki a while ago and I had some trouble with it like not being able to shutdown, restart, ... I've been able to solve those problems but there are still some huge ones that persist such as black screen after suspend/closing the lid and after sometime using loki it freezes for some reason and I'm not able to do anything (not even Ctrl + Alt + F1) and I have to restart by pressing the power button ..

Computer:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6440HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz

16GB RAM

Nvidia GTX 950M 2GB

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thank you

Comment: What video card driver are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57 for my Nvidia video card but I'm using my Intel video card to run loki because if I try using Nvidia, when I restart/shutdown/suspend my screen just goes black and It goes back to Intel after I force restart with the power button. And my kernel version is 4.7.5

Comment: Might be worth trying the latest Nvidia drivers and kernel

Comment: I went to the Nvidia drivers website and search for the most recent ones and it's version 367.57 .. As for the kernel, I don't really know how to know what's the latest version

Comment: Try this: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7548/5811

Comment: I've had a lot of problems with Loki, two different Nvidia cards and several different versions of the Nvidia drivers. I finally just switched over to Nouveau.

Comment: I've the same problem with GT 740M (driver 367.57).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with kernel 4.4.0 to 4.5 with open source video drivers.
I am no expert but I found this to be a common thread among people with this problem.
I updated kernel to 4.6 and it seems to have resolved the issue, albeit creating some smaller issues I am now working on...

Answer (score 0):

Like Mixy said there are known issues (that I've battled as well) with OpenSource Nvidia drivers and old NVidia drivers, prior to .375. After I move to proprietary Nvidia 375 everything started to work fine. Try to install "additional drivers" > apt update > set the driver to the latest