# The screen goes black when I suspend the laptop

Tags: release-loki, display, suspend

Recently I installed Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki and the laptop goes black when I want to lock/suspend it (Win+L). Then, I can't do anymore and I've to do a force shutdown.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See also https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/loki-freezes-and-black-screen-after-suspend