# graphics driver broken [solved]

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia

I recently installed Loki on my machine. I was running two monitors on an AMD FirePro 7000. I installed an Nvidia GTX 970, and only one monitor was being recognized. I tried various combinations of cables (HDMI, DisplayPort, and DVI).

After rebooting with a DVI cable, the monitor was showing garbage. Now I have no way to reach the greet screen. Any combination of cable boots to a screen full of vertical lines (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKB8e.jpg)

How might I be able to reinstall my graphics drivers?

EDIT: I noticed that the motherboard splash screen was taking much longer than before. I am unable to get into BIOS settings, boot menu, or anything that requires a keypress. I was going to reinstall the OS, but I can't do anything

[UPDATE] I removed the graphics card itself, and made it to the greet screen with a DVI cable plugged into the motherboard. I searched for nvidia packages with `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia` and removed anything with nvidia in the name.

Reinstalled the graphics card, and turned the machine on. DVI was still trashed, but plugging into HDMI gave me a login screen. Yay! used the instructions in [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/install-nvidia-dual-graphics-driver-on-loki), described below:

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list`

intel-something-or-other
nvidia-367

Then, with `$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, some great drivers installed. The greatest drivers. Everything works now, back to two monitors with an Nvidia GTX 970 from an AMD FirePro 7000.

Comment: Is it possible to edit your answer and put the solution as an answer? It looks like the question was never resolved, but actually you solved it yourself. I hope that's not too much trouble.