# Long load time on bootup with nvidia graphics card

Tags: boot

I installed Loki fresh from a usb stick. I replaced the graphics card and had some trouble (see [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9381/graphics-driver-broken-solved)) After fixing this, the bootup process takes an extremely long time.

Bootup with the AMD card was fast.

Bootup with no graphics card is fast.

Bootup with Nvidia card is slow. Before, time from reboot button to login screen was < 1 minute. Now it spends at least that long on the motherboard splash screen. Let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: Boot with the Nvidia card (don't do it if you have just booted with that one) and run the command `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Now check what is taking so long to boot and post that line here.

Answer (score 1):

Reflashing my Gigabyte motherboard BIOS to the newest version (F18 - F20) fixed it.