# How long does it take to update driver in elementary OS?

Tags: updates, graphic-drivers, drivers

I tried to get drivers for nvidia graphics card following this [post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/install-nvidia-dual-graphics-driver-on-loki).
But the terminal seems to get stuck at "Building generic module", It takes a long time...
Is it normal? If yes, how long does it take? 
(It is a fairly old laptop with 2 Gib RAM and an i7 processor, no SSD)